# Search - Userprofiles sps3 and sps4

Tags: search, user-profile, people-search

I´m using in my SharePoitn 2013 environment the enterprise search to crawl the user profiles.

What is the difference between sps3 and sps4?

**sps3://mysitehost**

**sps3s://mysitehost (https)**

and

**sps4://mysitehost**

**sps4s://mysitehost (https)**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That's easy, SPS4 is one better! (Sorry, couldn't resist, like turning it up to 11).

In reality, you can just use SPS3 (and SPS3S for SSL) for your crawl address. It will work just fine as long as your Search Crawl account has the correct permission on the User Profile Service App. (Specifically "Retrieve People Data for Search Crawlers")

Comment: Do you know why it is named like that? Sps3 and 4? Is there any logic to this naming convention?

Comment: I tried to do a bit of research for you and came up empty, so I looked at a few productions farms and all use SPS3. I believe it is just a shorthand protocol for the User Profile Service.